# .net / wcf: deserialization of an xml with xsi:type

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

I have a little wcf server wich receive POST request with a XML (note that I HAVE NO CONTROL OVER THE XML). I can deserialize it with no problem unless it has a xsi:type = "something" attribute.

When I try to serialize my class, everthing works (even the xsi:type attribute).

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node1 Att1="" Att2=""
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:type="SOMETHING" 
    xmlns="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1"  
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Node2/>
</Node1>
```

The server throw a bad request (400) when I send this XML, but if I remove the "xsi:type="SOMETHING"", everthing works.

Here is what the server send when i ask for the serialised class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Node1 Att1="" Att2="" xsi:type="SOMETHING"
    xmlns="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Node2/>
</Node1>
```

If the serialization works well, why the deserialization don't?

Here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ConsoleApplicationTest.dom
{

[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Node1", Namespace = "http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1")]
public class Test
{
    //attributes
    [XmlAttribute("Att1")]
    public string Att1 = "";
    [XmlAttribute("Att2")]
    public string Att2 = "";

    [XmlAttribute("type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type="typetypetype";



    [XmlElement("Node2")]
    public string node2 = "";


}




}
```

Please help me :(

Comment: I think the reason is that 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute has a special meaning when deserialising. It should tell the the serializer that it should create an object that maps to this particular type. Is this your intended behavioyr?

Comment: I tried to map to a class SOMETHING, but it didn't help. The truth is I don't need that information at all, but it will allways be in the xml i receive :/

Comment: Would it help then to mark this Type property with [XmlIgnore]?

Comment: No, [XmlInore] doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this class:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Node1", Namespace = "http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1")]
public class SOMETHING
{
    //attributes
    [XmlAttribute("Att1")]
    public string Att1 = "";
    [XmlAttribute("Att2")]
    public string Att2 = "";

    [XmlElement("Node2")]
    public string node2 = "";


}
```

My code works fine

```
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SOMETHING));

    SOMETHING t = (SOMETHING)ser.Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the server can only receive xml/json, I can't deserialize from a stream or a string.
I need to use only my class to deserialize :/